# How to manage dynamic path in app to Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have data in my Firebase that looks something like this (this is a Javascript-based web app):

```
bids
    400
        1
            50.00
        2
            60.00
    401
        1
            55.00
        2
            65.00
```

400 and 401 refer to auction numbers. 1 and 2 refer to individual lots within each auction. And the 3rd level is a bid amount.

I am displaying a list of all bids to the user by watching for child_added like this:

```
dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child(lotno).on('child_added', function(data){...});
```

When the app first loads, there is no auction or lot number assigned yet. And as the auction progresses, the lot number (and possibly even the auction number) will change many times.

I am confused as to how to maintain a real-time list of bids given this scenario. When the app first loads, my variables "auction" and "lotno" have the value "undefined", therefore I get an "invalid path" error from Firebase.

I'm also not sure what happens to my child_added if a variable (and therefore, the path) changes. Will child_added load all the existing data at the new path, and start watching for new children from that point forward?

Any advice on how to handle the initial state of the app, where the variables are not populated yet?

Comment: I provided some feedback in an answer below. But it's not really clear to me what your problem is. If my answer is not what you're looking for, consider expanding the code in your question a bit, so that it provides a minimal, *complete*, verifiable example of the problem you're asking about: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're building your query like this:

```
dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child(lotno).on(...
```

You will have to create attach a new listener (and turn `off` the existing listener) every time one of the `action` or `lotno` variables changes.

It sounds like there can only be a single *current lot* at a time, which might make it more useful to model that into your data model:

```
bids
    400
        1
            50.00
        2
            60.00
    401
        1
            55.00
        current
            65.00
```

Then once the bidding on the current lot has finished, you can "retire" it to its proper lotnumber slot and have the next lot become the `current`. With a data structure like this, your listener for an auction could always be watching `current`:

```
dataRef.child('bids').child(auction).child('current').on(...
```

Comment: I think the missing piece to the puzzle (for me) is creating new listeners (and turning old listeners off) dynamically, as the auction progresses. Is there documentation on how to do that properly? Wondering if you are aware of any good examples.

Comment: The documentation on Firebase's website is fairly complete and quite readable. Turning off listeners is done through `off`: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching-callbacks