# Handling multiple URLs in Firebase for references?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a situation, having multiple users, all of them have unique hashId assigned to them, which makes their URL different.

```
users/hashId/bla/blah
```

The only difference in these URLs is hashId value.

While my client side updates the data in firebase, I need to apply server interactions to the child_added event listener in the node end.

> App can have any number of users, how to scale child_added for each
>   URL? Is there any concept of dynamic Urls?

As reference to every URL is new, I'm not sure of this situation. Also I do not wish to go with a for loop, for dynamic event binding.

P.S: Comparatively new to Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be certain from your description, but are you looking for this?

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.child("bla/blah").val());
});
```

If you''d prefer to only get the value of `blah` for each user, then you should modify your data model to separate the data:

```
users_bla_blah
  $uid
    valueOfBlaBlah
users
  $uid
    otherProps
```

Then you can simply listen for:

```
var ref = db.ref("users_bla_blah");
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037813/how-to-manage-dynamic-path-in-app-to-firebase-data , Got this. And it works. How stupid of me, that I didn't think of using child(). Thanks :)